# I am trying to update my simple to do list when an item from the list is deleted, but the page does not update even though I render the index.ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

**What I am trying to do**

- I am making a basic to do list with expressjs as backend
- I am using ejs js to check when a user clicks on a task
- I then use ajax to post this to the back end with the item to be deleted
- Backend deletes item from the list
- The backend updates the frontend
  **What isn't working**
- I log the updated list in the console and it shows the item has been deleted
- In the post request at backend I tell it to render the index.ejs again with the updated task list
- It doesn't
- When I reload the page the item that has been deleted dissappears
- I have realised with the ajax when I try to console log things like hello it isn't logged
- In the backend when I do res.send('hello') nothing is updated in the post /delete function

**Frontend ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Proton Planner</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <h1>Proton Planner</h1>
    <% if (locals.tasks) { %>
        <% for (var ind = 0; ind<locals.tasks.length; ind++) { %>
        <!-- Change the id and for for each checkbox-->
        <div class="form-check">
            <div class="checker">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault<%=ind%>">
            </div>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault<%=ind%>">
                <%= tasks[ind] %>
            </label>
          </div>
          <% } %>
    <% } %>
    <form action="/submit" method="post">
        <input placeholder="Add a task" type="text" id="task" name="task" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <!-- JS scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <script>
// AREA OF INTEREST --------------------------------------------------------------
        $('.checker').on('click', function() {
            
            var itemDel = $(this).next().text().trim();
            console.log('Item deleted', itemDel);
    
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/delete',
                data: {
                   itemDel,
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log('ajax post success')
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/',
                        success: function(response) {
    // Handle the successful response here
                            console.log(response);
                            console.log('ajax get success')
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    // Handle errors here
                            console.error(error);
                        }
                
            }) 
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    // Handle errors here
                    console.error(error);
                }
            })
            

        })
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Backend expressjs**

```
// Imports
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

// Constants
const app = express();
// MAKE NOTE OF THIS IN TRELLO 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
const port = 3000;
let taskList = [];

// Getting the absolute file path
import { dirname } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

// App.use
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

// App.get
app.get("/", (req, res) => { 
    res.render("index.ejs", { tasks: taskList })
  });

// App.post for new task
app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
    let newTask = req.body["task"]
    taskList.push(newTask)  
    console.log(taskList)
    res.render("index.ejs", { tasks: taskList })
});
// Look here -------------------------------------------------------------------
//App.post to delete a task
app.post("/delete", (req, res) => {
  var remItem = req.body.itemDel;
  console.log(remItem)
  /*
  for (var item = 0; item<taskList.length; item++) {
    if (remItem == taskList[item]) {
      taskList.splice(item, 1);
      taskList.push(remItem);
      console.log(taskList)
    }
  }*/
  var i = 0;
  while (i < taskList.length) {
    if (taskList[i] === remItem) {
      taskList.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      ++i;
    }}
    console.log(taskList);
  res.send('Hello')
  //res.render("index.ejs", { tasks: taskList });
});

// App.listen
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
  });
```

I think I have explained everything above?

Comment: You are just loading a html here, not replacing the page content with it. `window.reload` will work here instead

Comment: It is saying window is not defined. I then did res.window.reload and it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting to the homepage using res.redirect('/')

Comment: Redirect won't work because op is using ajax

Comment: Yes I tried it but nothing happened

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).